# How to get JAI + JBoss 7.1.1 + Geoserver 2.3.0 to work?

Tags: geoserver, jboss, jai

I'm trying to use JBoss 7.1.1 instead Tomcat.

My configuration:

- Ubuntu 12.04 64bit
- Oracle JDK 1.7 (env varibles are set correctly)
- JAI and JAI ImageIO installed by following help document: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html (this manual works with Tomcat)
- Geoserver 2.3.0 (war file)
- Jboss 7.1.1 (out-the-box)

Problem: After following the documents, both JAI and JAI ImageIO are not show as true in "server state" panel (Has Geoserver not found them?).

I did the same steps like in Tomcat, but I'm a total noob with Jboss. I think that JBoss does not search in CLASSPATH for JAI extension, and it need to include JAI like a JBoss "module", but I couldnot find any information about that.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I have included the jar files, from the JAI installation file, in the WAR file, inside the path "/WEB-INF/lib", and now shown this in the panel:
[image]

**UPDATE 2:** I put the .so (from JAI packages) in "/usr/lib", no luck. My co-worker is compiling Geoserver, in Eclipse, to see if we see happening in Jboss while loading the JAI. We hope to find a solution (I will share it here).

**UPDATE 3:** It's a problem in Jboss configuration. We will write down the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: I believe you will need to disclose some specific details of your problem in order to make this an answerable question.  What does "never shows like true" mean?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. The problem is JAI libraries never are loaded by geoserver. In "Server State" administration page always show as "false".

Comment: I updated the original post. Sorry for my english... :(

Comment: Hi have another issue with java 1.7 x64: Could not initialize class org.geotools.image.ImageWorker on very wms request. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Tommaso check the jai installation, if it's correctly installed, and is your correct OS (x64 or x86). And dont remove the JAI/IMAGEIO jar from the Geoserver WAR...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, I have tried importing the geoserver code as an eclipse project and then deploying it to a JBoss instance and in that case JAI libraries are loaded without any problem. That is because eclipse launch their own paths to load that libraries, so if you want JBoss to be capable of loading these libraries you have to:

1. Copy your .so or .dll in the path $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386 or $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64
2. Make a new JBoss modules for the libraries:
   $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/sun/media/jai/
   $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/sun/media/jai/imageio/

Comment: It's do the work!... i copied .so to $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64 and load the .jar files like modules in Jboss.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it will work somehow by installing JAI and JAI ImageIO as jboss modules but I didn't managed it. The solution I've found is to install the native libraries into the java home that is used by JBoss and then add the following lines to $JBOSS_HOME/modules/sun/jdk/main/module.xml

```
            <path name="com/sun/image"/>
            <path name="com/sun/image/codec"/>
            <path name="com/sun/image/codec/jpeg"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/imageio/plugins"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/bmp"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/common"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/gif"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/jpeg"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/jpeg2000"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/pnm"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/png"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/plugins/tiff"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/spi"/>
            <path name="com/sun/imageio/stream"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/bmp"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/jpeg"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/gif"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/png"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/tiff"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/imageioimpl/common"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/jai"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/jai/codec"/>
            <path name="com/sun/media/jai/util"/>
            <path name="com/sun/medialib/mlib"/>
            <path name="javax/imageio/spi"/>
            <path name="javax/media/jai"/>
            <path name="javax/media/jai/util"/>
            <path name="javax/media/jai/widget"/>
            <path name="javax/media/jai/registry"/>
            <path name="javax/media/jai/operator"/>
```